# What is the proper name of a model that takes as input the output of another model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling, predictive-models, terminology

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am writing a paper and for the life of me can't remember the proper term for a model that works as follows.

`rawData -> model1 -> outputModel1 -> model2 -> outputModel2`

More specifically, I have created a linear regression model whose output I pass to a second linear regression model. One could imagine N models strung together like this.

I keep wanting to call this a hierarchical or multi-level model, but I know that isn't right: these types of models are synonymous with mixed models. I know that there is a proper name for this since I remember discussing it in a class that took awhile back. Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: The word ``cascaded'' comes to mind...

Comment: Hierarchical and multilevel are certainly "reserved" for mixed models so using them for this kind of model would certainly be confusing.

Comment: "Hierarchical models" is rather generic, so I do not see why it would not apply. In Econometrics, you also have "simultaneous equation models" where outputs of some equations are input of others.

Comment: What about just "two-stage" or "two-step" estimation?

Comment: I think this is stacking structure. There is a note book in kaggle for titanic problem like this.

Comment: What do you call the *output* of a linear model? A linear model is the distribution of a response variable conditional on covariates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is known as Cascaded classification/regression or Multi-stage classification/regression. It is a type of ensemble learning with some differences. You can find more in [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_classifiers).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if there exists at all a "proper name" for models that you describe, but I would call such models **chain models**, similarly to the *chain procedures*, introduced in the following paper: http://www.multxpert.com/doc/md2011.pdf. This term IMHO better reflects the *nature* of this type of models and, at the same time, prevents potential confusion with *hierarchical* and *multi-level* ones.